# MonoTouch: SystemSound not working on device

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

In MonoTouch 5.2.13 in the simulator the sound works. But on a real 5.1.1 device, it does not. No errors or messages reported.

Am I missing something?

```
    SystemSound sound;
    void PlayRevSound()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start Sound");
            //enable audio
            AudioSession.Initialize();
            //load the sound
            sound = SystemSound.FromFile("Images/rev.wav");
            sound.PlaySystemSound();
            Console.WriteLine("End Sound");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error Sound: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: carefully check the casing of your paths.  The device is case sensitive, the simulator is not (if using default file system settings).

Comment: Check if your device is muted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device was muted. [red faced]

When in doubt, it's often the simplest problem....